# C# key scan codes

Tags: c#, wpf, key, keyeventargs

Can I get this scan codes described here https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/rtl/keyboard/kbdscancode.html in C# WPF KeyEventArgs?

Comment: What to you need that for?

Comment: I must send this special codes for another app which is not written by me and can only receive this codes for pressed keys..for example "A" is 0x0041 and for "F5" 0x3F00 ..but in C# are different codes for Fkeys Ctrl+Fkey etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MapVirtualKey from user32.dll for this

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Program
{
    private const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0;
    private const uint VK_F5 = 116; // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=net-5.0

    [DllImport("user32.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
        EntryPoint = "MapVirtualKey",
        SetLastError = true,
        ThrowOnUnmappableChar = false)]
    private static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

    public static void Main()
    {
        var scanCodeForF5 = MapVirtualKey(VK_F5, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
        Console.WriteLine(scanCodeForF5.ToString("X"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately dotnetfiddle does not allow running the above code, but it outputs 3F. <strike>VK_F5 would be replaced by `(uint)KeyEventArgs.Key` for your case I believe.</strike>

**Edit**: It appears the value in the `System.Windows.Input.Key` enum don't match up with the value in my example which are from the `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` namespace, so the above code will not work on `KeyEventArgs.Key` directly.

**Edit 2**: You can use `KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey` from the `System.Windows.Input` namespace to convert from `System.Windows.Input.Key` to `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`.

So for your case this should work;
`var scanCodeForF5 = MapVirtualKey(KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(Key.F5), MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);`

Comment: I tried it by edit 2 and it works with F keys, but when i do Ctrl+F5 it only gives me the code for F5 key..but thanks for the base